# Bug in WinForm combobox control DotNet 4.8 - VS2019

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I'm writing a winforms app in C# (NOT ASP.NET!) and am getting an error on a combobox control (filled or not, selected or not) that looks like so:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'NonComVisibleBaseClass'
>  
>   Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'NonComVisibleBaseClass' : 'A QueryInterface call was made requesting the class interface of COM visible managed class 'ComboBoxUiaProvider'. However since this class derives from non COM visible class 'ComboBoxExAccessibleObject', the QueryInterface call will fail. This is done to prevent the non COM visible base class from being constrained by the COM versioning rules.'

I don't see anything wrong (It's a very very basic app to do some testing with) with the code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace SpeechDemoApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private SpeechSynthesizer _SS = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _SS.Speak(txtSpeech.Text.Trim());
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ivs = _SS.GetInstalledVoices();
            foreach (var iv in ivs)
            {
                ComboboxItem cboItem = new ComboboxItem();
                cboItem.Text = iv.VoiceInfo.Name;
                cboItem.Value = iv.VoiceInfo.Name;
                cboVoices.Items.Add(cboItem);
            }


        }

    }

    public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
}
```

The combobox fills correctly, however, when you click on the combobox, the error above is generated. I can't figure out what is going on. 
Note this is a WinForms application (sorry I have to keep mentioning this as no one reads posts before answering), NOT a WPF nor an ASP.NET app.

Comment: Is the speech synthesizer managed code or non managed code (from c++)? COM exception are normally is you are trying to call non managed code from managed c#.  You may need to call the methods using DLLImport.

Comment: try loading the combo box .text    and .value  with a dummy text or int   and not from the  iv voice info object   and see if your error goes away.    how the combo box .value  and the .Text work rely on some assumptions about  .ToString  and how  .Value can interrogate the object.   In effect is VoiceInfo not the ideal object and you need a dot net intermediary.

Comment: See my answer below (it has nothing to do w/ the speech library - I replicated this 4.8 bug in a new project)

Comment: The code posted here won't ever reproduce the issue. You ComboBoxItem is useless as shown here, so this is quite probably not what you're doing there nor those are actual object you're storing. Btw, this exception is optional, you can disable it.-- (`.Net Framework 4.8` is not *based on DotNetCore* and it works in Windows 7, of course.)

Comment: From Microsoft: "The JIT in .NET 4.8 is based on .NET Core 2.1 so all bug fixes and many code generation-based performance optimizations from .NET Core 2.1 are now available in the .NET Framework."

Comment: The combobox works just fine, actually. It loads fine, and selecting it does not crash, so long as it is not compiled w/4.8FW

Answer (score 3):

Recompiled in DotNetFramework 4.5, 4.6*, 4,7* and tested each sub-version and they all work perfectly.
This is a DotNetFramework 4.8 Bug, that, apparently, has not been reported/resolved to Microsoft.
Downgrading to 4.7.2 fixed the problem

To duplicate this issue - here is the complete and functioning code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SpeechDemoApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private SpeechSynthesizer _SS = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        private void btnSpeak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboVoices.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                _SS.SelectVoice(cboVoices.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
            _SS.Volume = trackBar1.Value;
            _SS.SpeakAsync(txtPhrase.Text.Trim());
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ivs = _SS.GetInstalledVoices();
            foreach (var iv in ivs)
            {
                ComboboxItem cboItem = new ComboboxItem();
                cboItem.Text = iv.VoiceInfo.Name;
                cboItem.Value = iv.VoiceInfo.Name;
                cboVoices.Items.Add(cboItem);
            }

            if (cboVoices.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                cboVoices.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private void cboVoices_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _SS.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
            base.OnClosing(e);
        }
    }



    public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
}
```

And the designer:

```
namespace SpeechDemoApp
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.cboVoices = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.txtPhrase = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnSpeak = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // cboVoices
            // 
            this.cboVoices.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.cboVoices.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cboVoices.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(41, 37);
            this.cboVoices.Name = "cboVoices";
            this.cboVoices.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 21);
            this.cboVoices.TabIndex = 0;
            this.cboVoices.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cboVoices_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // txtPhrase
            // 
            this.txtPhrase.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(41, 82);
            this.txtPhrase.Name = "txtPhrase";
            this.txtPhrase.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(664, 20);
            this.txtPhrase.TabIndex = 1;
            this.txtPhrase.Text = "This is a test of the Emergency Webcast System. If this were an actual emergency," +
    " you would be bleeding from all of your orifices.";
            // 
            // btnSpeak
            // 
            this.btnSpeak.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(41, 127);
            this.btnSpeak.Name = "btnSpeak";
            this.btnSpeak.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 23);
            this.btnSpeak.TabIndex = 2;
            this.btnSpeak.Text = "Speak";
            this.btnSpeak.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnSpeak.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSpeak_Click);
            // 
            // trackBar1
            // 
            this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(240, 127);
            this.trackBar1.Maximum = 100;
            this.trackBar1.Name = "trackBar1";
            this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(465, 45);
            this.trackBar1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.trackBar1.Value = 80;
            this.trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_Scroll);
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.trackBar1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSpeak);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtPhrase);
            this.Controls.Add(this.cboVoices);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form2_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cboVoices;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPhrase;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSpeak;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Encountered this error when trying to pull an old .Net Framework 4 winforms app into the modern ages. 4.7.2 will be "good enough" for my purposes though. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I am running Windows Server 2012 with same problem and same resolution.

Answer (score 3):

The work-around is to add the following to app.config:

```
<configuration>
  …
  <runtime>
    …
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.3=true"/>
    …
  </runtime>
  …
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'll have to give this a try on older apps. Moved to DotNetCore 5 (and now 6) where this issue doesn't exist. In addendum, this bug is still present on Windows 10.